# Рендер таблицы React + TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Как оптимальным образом реализовать процесс рендеринга данной таблицы?

У меня имеется таблица со следующими особенностями:
[image: Таблица]

- Возможность взаимодействия с ячейками, например, одной ячейки колонки периода, через контекстное меню правой кнопки мыши (редактирование, копирование, удаление).
- Присутствие фильтров для каждой колонки по различным критериям, таким как дата, сумма, роли, объекты и т.д.
- Возможность сворачивания каждой колонки.

[image: Скрытие колонки]